# powershell how to implement worker threads

Tags: multithreading, powershell, subprocess

I have a little performance issue in my script, so i would like to implement some sort of worker theads. but so far i have not been able to find a solution..

what im hoping for is something like this:

- start a pool of worker threads - these threads takes "commands" from a queue and process them
- the main script will write "commands" to the queue as it runs
- once complete the main will tell each thread to stop
- main will wait for all workers to end before exiting.

does anybody have en idea on how to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you investigated background jobs or runspace pools?

Comment: yes, i started with start-job, but so far have not had any luck communicating from the main thread to the job.

runspace; i have looked at a few examples, but it seems very complex, same with events.. 

i need to be able to handle 100.000 events per half hour ~95 events per sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help from the pointers made by Keith hill - i got it working - thanks a bunch...

Here is a snipping of the code that did my prove of concept:

```
function New-Task([int]$Index,[scriptblock]$ScriptBlock) {
    $ps = [Management.Automation.PowerShell]::Create()
    $res = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Index = $Index
        Powershell = $ps
        StartTime = Get-Date
        Busy = $true
        Data = $null
        async = $null
    }

    [Void] $ps.AddScript($ScriptBlock)
    [Void] $ps.AddParameter("TaskInfo",$Res)
    $res.async = $ps.BeginInvoke()
    $res
}

$ScriptBlock = {
    param([Object]$TaskInfo) 
    $TaskInfo.Busy = $false
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    $TaskInfo.Data = "test $($TaskInfo.Data)"
}

$a = New-Task -Index 1 -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock 
$a.Data = "i was here"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
$a
```

And here is the result proving that the data was communicated into the thread and back again:

```
Data       : test i was here
Busy       : False
Powershell : System.Management.Automation.PowerShell
Index      : 1
StartTime  : 11/25/2013 7:37:07 AM
async      : System.Management.Automation.PowerShellAsyncResult
```

as you can see the $a.data now have "test" in front

So thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Powershell workflows.

From [Windows PowerShell: What is Windows PowerShell Workflow?](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj884462.aspx)

> Workflows can also execute things in parallel, if you like. For
>   example, if you have a set of tasks that can run in any order, with no
>   interdependencies, then you can have them all run at more or less the
>   same time

Just do a search on "Powershell workflows" and you will find a good amount of documentation to get you started.

Comment: this might be a possibility, need to investigate this further.

Answer (score 0):

The basic approach to using a job is this:

```
$task1 = { ls c:\windows\system32 -r *.dll -ea 0 | where LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-21) }
$task2 = { ls E:\Symbols -r *.dll | where LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-21) }
$task3 = { Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mainfeed.aspx?Type=BlogsOnly | % Content }

$job1 = Start-Job $task1; $job2 = Start-Job $task2; $job3 = Start-Job $task3
Wait-Job $job1,$job2,$job3

$job1Data = Receive-Job $job1
$job2Data = Receive-Job $job2
$job3Data = Receive-Job $job3
```

If you need to have those background jobs waiting in a loop to do work as the main script dictates have a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891325/whats-the-best-way-to-pass-values-to-a-running-background-script-block) to see how to use MSMQ to do this.

Comment: Yes, i know start-job.. using that a lot - but so far i havnt been able to communicate with a task once it have been started - which is what i need.

Comment: Did you follow the link in the answer - which describes *exactly* how to do that?

Comment: Yes, but i can not use the messagequeuing service due to the server where this needs to be executed.

Comment: but perhaps this adds other possibilities, i need to investigate this further.

Comment: Your options are limited as I see it: jobs, runspaces, workflows.  Both jobs and workflows run "out-of-process" so will require some form of IPC.  Runspace pool may be your best shot since these run in-process so you should be able to use a .NET queue (BlockingCollection<T>) to pass data to the worker scripts.