# Powershell warm up script for site that doesn't wait for success response

Tags: powershell

I've got the following warm up script that works well for my apps (IIS apps with mulitple worker processes).  Needs about 1200 requests against 24 servers to warm them up sufficiently.

My issue is that it takes around 25 mins to complete as the request is waiting for the request to return successfully before continuing.

Is there a way to just fire the request and continue without waiting for the response?

Here's the powershell im using:

```
$Site = 'http://myipaddress173.28.36.20:1155/api/uri' #, 'http://173.28.20.78:1155/api/uri'
@($Site) | % {
Write-Host "Warming up $($_)"
$i=0
Do {
    $res = Invoke-RestMethod $_ -Method Post -ContentType 'application/json' -Headers @{Authorization="Bearer GHDSBBSXHHX637373dg"; Host="myurl.com"} -Body '{"accountId": 0,"domain":"my","language":"en"}'
    Write-Host "$i = $($_)"
    $i++
} While ($i -le 1200)
```

Comment: Maybe using `Invoke-Command` with the `-AsJob` switch could do it? Something like `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Invoke-RestMethod $_ -Method Post -ContentType 'application/json' -Headers @{Authorization="Bearer GHDSBBSXHHX637373dg"; Host="myurl.com"} -Body '{"accountId": 0,"domain":"my","language":"en"}'} -AsJob`

Comment: Or use [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job?view=powershell-6), see e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20182622/1701026

Comment: @Theo: `Invoke-Command -AsJob` only works with PS remoting.

Comment: @mklement0 Yes, you're right. I didn't read the description for the [-AsJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-6#parameters) switch properly. Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, have each request done in a separate thread.  But your command also concerns me here.  I assume your not actually using this code http://myipaddress173.28.36.20:1155/api/uri and the "MyIPaddress" is a cut/paste error.

Plus, it appears your not really interested in the actual result, and this 1200 seems like your just trying to generate 1200 hits against the same address. Is that really what you want?  My suggestions are:

```
# Force to an array, even if just one.
$Site = @('http://myipaddress173.28.36.20:1155/api/uri',http://173.28.20.78:1155/api/uri')

@($Site) | % {
   Write-Host "Warming up $($_)"
   $i=0

$Body = @{
"accountId": 0
"domain":"my"
"language":"en"}

$Headers = @{
Authorization="Bearer GHDSBBSXHHX637373dg"
Host="myurl.com"} 

$commands = "Invoke-RestMethod $_ -Method Post -ContentType 'application/json' -Headers $headers -Body $body"

Do {
    invoke-command $command -ComputerName localhost
    Write-Host "$i = $($_)"
#  Suggest adding a sleep here..
#  sleep -seconds 1
    $i++
} While ($i -le 1200)
```

Now, this will post 1200 times to the specific URL (if I did my code right), and then move on to the next.

This has the ability to make the machine your running it from slow to a crawl as it generates MANY,MANY web site hits in a split second (and could cause the server to experience a denial of service for a period of time, however short), as well as exhaust the number of outbound ports your client has free to make the connections.