# how to call variables from a running script to a different script powershell

Tags: variables, powershell, scripting

I want a script to get a variable from a different script which are both running on the system. Is that possible?

I have two scripts running on the system, and I want one script to pull a user-defined variable instead of asking the user to input the data twice

Comment: Here is another stackoverflow post that may answer your question: [Global Variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535419/powershell-setting-a-global-variable-from-a-function-where-the-global-variable-n)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both scripts are running concurrently, MSMQ would be one option:

[What's the best way to pass values to a running/background script block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891325/whats-the-best-way-to-pass-values-to-a-running-background-script-block)

Global Variables are only "Global" in the context of scopes in the current session. They aren't visible to a script running is a different session.

Answer (score 0):

Write it to a text file and have the other script read it. You can load up the text into a variable, then execute it as code using iex (Invoke-Expression).