# Powershell - updating textbox from start-job

Tags: wpf, multithreading, powershell, start-job

I've been working on moving over a WPF program I wrote in C# over to PowerShell, and I'm having a little issue with appending text in my RichTextBox from Start-Job It looks like I can call the Set-RichTextBox where ever, except for inside the scriptblock. Is there a workaround?

```
#outside the ScriptBlock
Set-RichTextBox -message "This does work"
#outside the ScriptBlock

$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {

function Set-RichTextBox
{
  param (
     [System.String]
     $message
  )
     $richTextBox1.Dispatcher.invoke([action]{       
     $richTextBox1.AppendText($message)      
     },"Normal")
 }

  Set-RichTextBox -message "This doesn't work"
  }
```

I can call RichTextBox anywhere except for within the Start-Job, I do not get any error messages. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to me it seems it works:

```
Remove-Job *

$job = Start-Job -Name Test -ScriptBlock {

    function Set-RichTextBox
    {
        param ([string]$message)

        $message
    }

    Set-RichTextBox -message "This should work..."
}

Start-Sleep 5
Get-Job |Where-Object {$PSItem.Name -eq "Test"} |Receive-Job
```

you might wanna have a look at:
[PowerShell: Creating Custom Objects](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7804.powershell-creating-custom-objects.aspx#Add-Type_C)

also these may or may not be related:

- [What's the best way to pass values to a running/background script block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891325/whats-the-best-way-to-pass-values-to-a-running-background-script-block/13897636#13897636)
- [Passing “native” object to background jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15382728/passing-native-object-to-background-jobs/15383951#15383951)